# Replacing file using "sort x.txt > x.txt" in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Why is it that "sort x.txt > x.txt" clears the contents of a file while "sort x.txt > y.txt" writes the sorted file to y.txt as you would expect

Comment: This is about bash shell scripting. I'm not sure what the consensus is, but this might be better for superuser.com, as it's not about programming per se.

Comment: this isn't cygwin specific behavior...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "as you would expect".  I would expect x.txt to be empty if you issue a command that truncates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell truncates `x.txt` before it invokes the command `sort x.txt`, so by the time the sort command is running, there is nothing to sort.

Just about all shells behave this way (including Windows CMD window); it is not just a feature of Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command, you're effectively telling the shell to open x.txt for write (>> would be append, which would be different), and then dump the results of "sort x.txt" into it - it just so happens that since it's opening the file for write, first, it effectively starts a new file with the name x.txt, and then executes sort x.txt, which sorts an empty file.

I'm not positive on the why the timing is as it is - but I believe it may keep you from trying to run a command to write to a file you don't have permission to write to, etc.  (aka- it opens it for write, first, to make sure it can).

Answer (score 0):

`sort a > b` open a and b together with a for reading and b for writing. as b for writing, it would be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

When executing the command, first of all the shell opens the output file to write the programs output to, effectively truncating it to zero length. Then it starts the sort command, and in the `sort x.txt > x.txt` case this sorts the newly empty file `x.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

When the shell sees the command `sort x.txt > x.txt` it sees that the output of the sort command needs to go into the file `x.txt`, so it opens the file `x.txt` for writing, this will wipe out the contents of the file, if the file already had anything in it.

If you want to avoid it, you can redirect the sort output to a temp file and later rename the temp file as x.txt